# My php code posting zero instead of form data in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following a youtube tutorial and trying a project. The code inserts zero instead my username and email.But it inserts the actual data for admin type and last login. Please go through my code and tell me where am I lagging. here is my code.

```
<?php

/** 
 * User Class for account 
 */

class User
{
    private $con;
    function __construct() {
        include_once("../database/db.php");
        $db = new Database(); 
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

    private function emailExists($email){
        $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = ? ");
        $pre_stmt ->bind_param("s",$email);
        $pre_stmt ->execute() or die($this->con->error);
        $result = $pre_stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }  
    public function createUserAccount($username,$email,$password,$usertype)
    {
     if ($this->emailExists($email)) {
            return "EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS";
        }else{
            $pass_hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,["cost"=>8]);
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d");
            $notes = "";
            $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`username`, `email`, `password`, `usertype`, `register_date`, `last_login`, `notes`)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $pre_stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$username,$email,$pass_hash,$usertype,$date,$date2,$notes);  
            $result = $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error); 
            if ($result) {
                return $this->con->insert_id;
               }else{
                   return "SOME_ERROR";
               }
         }
    }
}

$user = new User();
echo $user->createUserAccount("admin5","mail4@mail.com","123456789","Other");

?>
```

Comment: Please show your table schema.

Comment: The function `createUserAccount()` seams to be prone for a **race condition** if the email column does not has a unique key in the MySQL table.

Comment: "My php code posting zero instead of **form data** in database" You talk about form data? Where is the HTML form code? Besides you are using hardcoded values in the code `$user->createUserAccount("admin5","mail4@mail.com","123456789","Other");`.. Nothing in this code is suggesting you are using form data..

Comment: yes i'm trying to insert the data manually into my database.

Comment: yeah, err the table schema might help here. Make sure your username and email columns are strings/varchars

Comment: Aaaah:( :(  ashamed of myself , I changed the email columns.It worked thank you so much..